# authorize.net sdk controller.execute() throws an error There was an error generating the XML document

Tags: c#, .net, reference, .net-assembly, authorize.net

I am having an error on the sample project of Authorize.Net.

I am currently using a Soap service of Authorize.Net and upgrading to the new Authorize.Net API but I wanted a switch to use both services at a time because of the requirement.

I introduced a switch to use a new or old API in the application.

The new Authorize API Guide and sample project can be found on the link below.
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html

I was debugging and found that the sample project is running perfectly unless I included it in my existing solution which is already has a reference of an old version of the authorize.net API.

Below is the snapshot of an error.

[image]

I can provide more detail if necessary.

Comment: the following post may help you troubleshoot the issue: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Authorize-Net-SDK-Error-quot-There-was-an-error-generating-the/td-p/72043

Comment: @MansourHamcherif thanks for your concern, the link you shared I already visited and nothing found helpful.